# C++ Class composition relationship - make class attribute static & constant

Tags: c++, static, attributes

Working on a project where one of my classes includes an instance of a defined class that functions as a Random Number Generator. This has worked as a composition relationship and has worked fine, but I've had it recommended to me that it would be better practice to have the Random Number Generator instance set as `private`, `static` and `const`. 
I have put the attribute in the `private:` section of the class, and put the `static` and `const` operators before the datatype. This hasn't come up with any compilation errors or exceptions yet, but I'm sure it can't be this simple.

Does anyone know if there are any further changes that I would have to make inside the RandomNumberGenerator class itself? I've had a read up on static data  members in classes but nothing seems to apply directly to this situation.

Any help greatly appreciated.
Class declarations shown below, full definitions can be provided if necessary:

```
class Cat
{
public:
    Cat(Mouse* p_mouse);
    Cat(const int& x, const int& y, Mouse* p_mouse);
    ~Cat();
    Mouse* p_mouse_;
    bool isAtPosition(const int& x, const int& y) const;
    bool hasCaughtMouse() const;
    void chaseMouse();
    void updatePosition(const int& dx, const int& dy);
    //access coordinates (set to private)
    int getX() const;
    int getY() const;
    //access symbol (set to private)
    char getSymbol() const;
private:
    int x_, y_;
    const char symbol_ = CAT;
    const static RandomNumberGenerator rng_;
    void spotMouse(Mouse* p_mouse);
    void positionAtRandom();
};

class RandomNumberGenerator
{
public:
    //constructors
    RandomNumberGenerator();
    //assessors
    int getRandomValue(const int&) const;
private:
    //supporting functions
    void seed();
};
```

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: "I'm sure it can't be this simple." Why not?

Comment: Posting the relevant code makes things much simpler and easier to understand

Comment: I'm afraid no one will be able to answer the question unless you provide a summary of your current code.

Comment: Class declarations added to question, let me know if you need anything more! @UchiaItachi

Comment: @marcuthh Do you need the `rng_` to be `const` ? I assume you're aware that you can't call any non-const functions from const member functions for ex: seed() from getRandomValue().

Comment: I did think that, this is why I'm inquiring. I was advised to make it const static but don't see how that would fit with what it currently is. I don't know if there's a way to reformat any of the class method's so it still works the same. @UchiaItachi